# How to test function that creates and injects a dependency

Tags: unit-testing, go, dependency-injection

My question is how do you decide where to inject a dependency, and how do you test the function in which the dependency is first injected into a function?

For example, I'm refactoring some Go code to use dependency injection with the goal of having the code be more testable.

This is what my refactored code looks like:

```
type FooIface interface {
  FooFunc()
}

type Foo struct {}

func (f *Foo) FooFunc() {
  // Some function I would like to stub
}

func main() {
  OuterFunction()
}

func OuterFunction() {
  fooVar := &Foo{}
  InnerFunction(fooVar)
  // Other stuff
}

func InnerFunction(f *FooIface) {
  f.FooFunc()
  // Other stuff
}
```

I'm able to easily test InnerFunction by creating a mock struct that implements FooIface with a stubbed FooFunc() so all is good here. **However, what if I wanted to test OuterFunction()? Then how would I stub FooFunc() from there since the injected dependency is created in OuterFunction()?**

Do I have to move the creation of the &Foo{} struct up one level out of OuterFunction() by creating it in main and then injecting it into OuterFunction()?

In other words, **how would you test the function that creates and injects the dependency**?

Comment: One option would be: https://play.golang.org/p/_Ow3rM7IH_f

Comment: I'm wondering what framework you are using for dependency injection?  We at Oracle are creating one named Dargo (https://github.com/jwells131313/dargo).  It has some features specifically for unit testing (Rank).  If you could take a look at it we would appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Often when people talk about dependency injection, it's in the context of creating objects (or in Go's case structs).

The canonical way to do this in Go is to use a `New` function such as `object_name.New(...)` or `package_name.NewObjectName(...)`. These functions take in the objects dependencies and output an instance of the object.

Above you are doing a lot of your code in static functions. Could it be inverted into objects that are created and have methods on them? This is sometimes called inversion of control.

```
type Foo {
    bar Bar
    baz Baz
}

func NewFoo(bar Bar, baz Baz) *Foo {
    return &Foo{ bar: bar, baz: baz }
}

func (foo *Foo) X() {
    foo.bar.Y()
    foo.baz.Z()
}
```

This model could be extended to multiple levels so testing is easier.

```
foo := NewFoo(
    NewBar(...),
    NewBaz(...),
)
```

Here is a [post](https://medium.com/@zach_4342/dependency-injection-in-golang-e587c69478a8) that might be helpful.

Comment: Suppose I used your NewFoo function to give me back a Foo struct inside of main or some other function. Even if I were to use your NewFoo() function, how would I test the function that I called NewFoo from (if I wanted to test some method on one of the structs inside of NewFoo)?

Comment: You could unit test each struct using it’s own New. You can test multiple together by mocking out the whatever subparts and leaving the rest. If you really need to test a static function (like a main) you could make the new function a variable NewFoo = func() *Foo { ... } and then you can overwrite the variable for tests. Beware - I only use that strategy as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Dargo](https://github.com/jwells131313/dargo) injection framework you can bind versions of your interfaces or structs with a higher Rank, which would then be used in your code rather than the things bound by your normal code.

Lets say you have some services defined like this in your normal code:

```
var globalLocator ioc.ServiceLocator

type AnExpensiveService interface {
    DoExpensiveThing(string) (string, error)
}

type NormalExpensiveServiceData struct {
}

func (nesd *NormalExpensiveServiceData) DoExpensiveThing(thingToDo string) (string, error) {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    return "Normal", nil
}

type SomeOtherServiceData struct {
    ExpensiveService AnExpensiveService `inject:"AnExpensiveService"`
}

func init() {
    myLocator, err := ioc.CreateAndBind("TestingExampleLocator", func(binder ioc.Binder) error {
        binder.Bind("UserService", SomeOtherServiceData{})
        binder.Bind("AnExpensiveService", NormalExpensiveServiceData{})

        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    globalLocator = myLocator
}

func DoSomeUserCode() (string, error) {
    raw, err := globalLocator.GetDService("UserService")
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    userService, ok := raw.(*SomeOtherServiceData)
    if !ok {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Unkonwn type")
    }

    return userService.ExpensiveService.DoExpensiveThing("foo")

}
```

Now you don't want to call the expensive service in your test code.  In the following test code the expensive service is replaced by a mock service, **with a higher rank**.  When the test calls the user code the mock is used in place of the normal expensive code.  Here is the test code:

```
type MockExpensiveService struct {
}

func (mock *MockExpensiveService) DoExpensiveThing(thingToDo string) (string, error) {
    return "Mock", nil
}

func putMocksIn() error {
    return ioc.BindIntoLocator(globalLocator, func(binder ioc.Binder) error {
        binder.Bind("AnExpensiveService", MockExpensiveService{}).Ranked(1)

        return nil
    })
}

func TestWithAMock(t *testing.T) {
    err := putMocksIn()
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err.Error())
        return
    }

    result, err := DoSomeUserCode()
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err.Error())
        return
    }

    if result != "Mock" {
        t.Errorf("Was expecting mock service but got %s", result)
        return
    }
}
```

When DoUserCode is called the UserService is looked up and instead of getting the normal implementation it is instead injected with the mock.

After that the test just verifies that it's the mock that got injected rather than the normal code.

That's the basics of unit testing with Dargo!  I hope it helps